# Tried using a breakpoint but my code on the developer tools is in red and can't hover over the values

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-developer-tools

Anyone know what this means and how to fix it? I'd like to be able to hover over the values on the breakpoint but half the code is in red for some reason. I am using react.

[image]

Comment: Hi @scotth527 could you please provide a code sample ? Otherwise it'll be difficult to help you

Comment: @t3__rry, heey sorry I just added the picture of the screen. My console is not getting any syntax error but I've seen this sometimes where part of the code is all rd and can't hover over the values when I put a breakpoint.